# dark band behind the object

Tags: rendering, lighting

I'm a newbie here, so sorry beforehand if this is a very obvious question.

Every time I render a dark band appears behind my object. When I get out of camera mode, I cannot figure out where this dark band is coming from. If I re-position the background planes, I can get to change the dark band geometry. But I have not been able to make it disappear. Using Blender 2.79
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Just for the record, it was a problem of camera clipping. After increasing the camera clipping end, the problem was solved.

Comment: glad you found an answer.  :)